# Batch INSERT on multiple queries is throwing foreign key violation

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I am following [this](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost) to do batch INSERT
with two queries. The first query inserts into `<tableone>` and the second query insert into `<tabletwo>`.

The second table has a foreign key constraints that references `<tableone>`.

The following code is how I am handling the batch inserts

```
batchQuery.push(
  insertTableOne,
  insertTableTwo
);

const query = pgp.helpers.concat(batchQuery);
db.none(query)
```

`insertTableOne` looks like

```
INSERT INTO tableone (id, att2, att3) VALUES 
(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'c', 'd'), (3, 'e', 'f'), ...
```

`insertTableTwo` looks like

```
INSERT INTO tabletwo (id, tableone_id) VALUES 
(10, 1), (20, 2), (30, 3), ...
```

with a constraint on `<tabletwo>`

```
CONSTRAINT fk_tabletwo_tableone_id
  FOREIGN KEY (tableone_id)
  REFERENCES Tableone (id)
```

upon `db.none(query)` I am getting a `violates foreign key constraint "fk_tabletwo_tableone_id"`

Does the above query not execute in sequence? First insert into table one, then insert into table two?

Is this an issue with how the query is being commited? I have also tried using a transaction shown by the example in the linked page above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should first log all the queries being executed, so you can see the exact sequence. Then you can re-run it in pgAdmin, and see where the problem lies in your case. Then it will be possible to figure out how to fix it. Use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to get all the queries, or at least event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query).

Comment: the query event helped me identify the SQL mistake that was leading to this problem. Just installed pg-monitor. Amazing!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you read through to the documentation for the `spex.batch()` method (which is used by the `pgp.helpers.concat()` method from your linked example) says of the `values` argument:

> Array of mixed values (it can be empty), to be resolved
>   asynchronously, in no particular order.

See http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch

You probably need to look at another method rather than using `batch()`.

I'd suggest chaining the dependent query using a `.then()` after the first insert has completed, ie. something like `db.none(insertTableOne).then(() => db.none(insertTableTwo))`

Comment: His problem is not with method `batch`, it is with not chaining the dependency correctly. He needs to find where he is breaking the dependency chain, and fix that. By the way, method `batch` instead of promises can take functions that create and return promises, so it is quite universal. That could also fix the dependency.

Comment: Noted with thanks; I've added a simple example of chaining the queries to my answer.